# Deleting Azure App Registration from Linux Terminal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I wanted to know if there is a way to delete Azure App Registrations from the Linux Terminal? I couldn't find the command for it in the azure documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install both Azure Powershell and the Azure CLI on Linux. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurermps-maclinux?view=azurermps-4.4.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

To delete the app registrations:

1.Run the `Login-AzureRMAccount` command and log in again using your global admin account.
2. Enter `Get-AzureRmADApplication` to get a list of all App Registrations.
3. Run `Remove-AzureRmADApplication -objectid <ObjectId from above>` for each App Registration found in your Azure Active Directory, making sure you enter “Y” to confirm that you want to delete it.

You can also use the script below to find and delete all App Registrations in one shot:

```
$ObjectIds = (Get-AzureRmADApplication).ObjectId
For ($i=0; $i -lt $ObjectIds.Length; $i++)
{
            Remove-AzureRmADApplication -objectid $ObjectIds[$i]
}
```

Comment: Can I not do the same using Azure CLI? I specifically wanted to achieve this using Azure CLI

Comment: Yes you can. Just use az ad app delete. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-delete

Comment: It's the equivalent command to Remove-AzureRmADApplication in Azure Powershell.